# CentOS 6 - Inodes full - can't delete folder containing files

Tags: centos, postfix

I have a CentOS 6 server at rackspace with 40GB of space.  My server kept crashing with 'no space left on device' errors but there is over 50% free.

When I run df-i this is the output:

```
/dev/xvda1           2490368 2490351      17  100% /
```

I traced the problem to postdrop I think.  Before I disabled postfix and postdrop the inodes would fill up immediately as soon as I freed any up.

From what I can see, there are thousands upon thousands of files being created in /var/spool/postfix/maildrop.  The folder itself is 67MB.  I can't "ls" the folder, I've tried to "rm -rf maildrop/" which just hangs for a long time.

How can I remove this folder. I don't even use mail on the server so I've disabled postfix and postdrop and sendmail.

```
drwx-wx---. 2 postfix postdrop  67M Dec 18 18:25 maildrop
```

Just wanted to update:

```
ls -1 | xargs -I{} rm {}
```

the above command solved the problem

It took 48 hours on and off.  There appeared to be almost 2,000,000 files in the /var/spool/postfix/maildrop folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a directory full of files, normally you can not just remove all files with rm

Try with:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Or try with:

```
ls -1 /path/to/directory | xargs -I{} rm {}
```

In other words you have to try to split the command in two, a part that handle the files and another that remove the files.

When you have a zillion of files into one directory you can't remove files using commands like rm. because rm in any case iterate between all files and directory.

Comment: Normally "rm -rf foldername" should just delete the entire folder though.  So wouldn't running 'find' and then 'rm' take even longer on that folder.  I'm going to assume there are a hundreds of thousands of files in there?

Comment: what would ls -1 | xargs -I{} rm {} do exactly?

Comment: Will execute one rm for file, you could also try with ls -1 | xargs rm but some versions of xargs doesn't work well. Can't handle so many files

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try both methods and see what works.  I need to get my ssh session to stop closing after inactivity though otherwise this command will never finish.

Comment: I had directories with 300k files... This solution works.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm do you really want to kill your server?
So don' t use "\;" in

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

This command will run a "rm" command for EACH file!

Use the "find" command the right way:

```
find /directory/ -name ‘*’ -exec rm {} +
```

this will call the "rm" command only for found files.
And your server will thank you! ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

After receiving various errors trying to execute any of the commands freedev suggested, I ended up cleaning it up like this:

```
rm -f 0*
rm -f 1*
rm -f 2*
[...]
rm -f 9*
```

You might want to do first a `rm -f 00*` to estimate how long will it take